How to use environment variables for runner group GitHub actions
I'm unable to access environment variables when specifying a runner group in GitHub actions.
I tried to use environment variables to specify a runner group, but now I don't think its possible.
I tried it like this:
name: Turn on maintenance mode

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: false
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      maintenance-text:
        description: 'The text that will be displayed when maintenance mode is on.'
        required: true
jobs:
  maintenance-mode-toggle:
    environment: Acceptance
    runs-on: 
      group: ${{ vars.RUNNER_GROUP }}
      labels: ${{ vars.IIS_APPLICATION_LABEL }}
    name: Turn Maintenance Mode On
    steps:
      - name: 'IIS: Enable maintenance mode'
        run: |  
          echo ${{ inputs.maintenance-text }} > app_offline.htm;
        working-directory: ${{ vars.IIS_APPLICATION_DIRECTORY }}

but this wont work because the environment isn't set yet so il get an empty string, however there is no way to set the environment on a higher level.
Then I tried it like this:
name: Elog - Maintenance Mode

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: false

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        type: choice
        description: 'In which environment do you want to enable maintenance mode?'
        options:
          - Acceptance
          - Production
        required: true
      toggle:
        type: choice
        description: 'Do you want to turn maintenance mode on or off?'
        options:
          - 'on'
          - 'off'
        required: true
      message:
        description: 'The message that will appear on the maintenance page'
jobs:
  deploy-maintenance-mode:
    if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' }}
    name: Maintenance Mode Toggle
    uses: ./.github/workflows/maitenance-template-workflow.yml
    environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
    with:
      application-pool: default
      environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
      toggle: ${{ inputs.toggle }}
      runner-group: ${{ vars.RUNNER_GROUP }}
      iis-application-label: ${{ vars.IIS_APPLICATION_LABEL}}
      message: ${{ inputs.message }}

but again this doesn't work because if I try to specify the environment in this job it wants me to turn it into a normal job.
So is there any way to specify the runner group using environment variables? Right now I have it just hardcoded in the yaml files because I see no way to specify them dynamically.

I tried to use environment variables ... but this wont work because the environment isn't set yet so i'll get an empty string. This part isn't clear, why isn't the environment set yet? You specified environment: Acceptance in your job, did you not create the environment and set the variables there beforehand?

I did but it wont work keep getting empty strings, the vars work when used in the steps level but not on the runs-on level. It might just not be supported on github actions but I cant find something concrete about it anywhere

Ok, got it. In that case going for the second option with a reusable workflow should work, however in that case, you don't set the environment on the main workflow calling the reusable, like you did there. You'll only set the environment in the reusable workflow jobs, using the inputs.environment inform from the main workflow.

@GuiFalourd yeah but then it still isnt able to get environment variables to set the runner group in the runs-on

You'll need to send those variables as input as well
